# How may I perform OCIPing (or equivalent) from a .Net application?

Tags: .net, oracle11g, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

A legacy C++ application routine pings our Oracle 11g database using the OCI C Library method [OCIPing()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnoci/miscellaneous-functions.html#GUID-7223B6DC-12C5-4C7E-80D2-83FB35655BE1):

```
sword OCIPing ( OCISvcCtx     *svchp,
                OCIError      *errhp,
                ub4            mode );
```

This application is being replaced by a modern C#.Net application and I cannot see an obvious API providing the same functionality. Does one exist that allows calls either .Net library, REST interface, etc?

What is the right way to do this? I imagine the C API *can* be called through a .Net application but if there's a more modern replacement API it would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how it is in case of C#.Net, but in case of Java Oracle managed to extend JDBC standard by adding `boolean isValid(int timeout) throws SQLException`. Newer version of JDBC drivers do call `OCIPing()`. It is the simplest fastest way to detect that DB connection is still alive.

If C#.Net does not have anything like that, you will have to call some simple SQL regularly.

Another option: you can also use TCP Keepalive in Oracle connection by adding`(ENABLE=BROKEN)` into databases connection string and tuning some Kernel parameters(registers). Like:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\KeepAliveTime
```

In such a case probe packets will not be sent by your application but by OS Kernel. By adding `(ENABLE=BROKEN)`, the driver will call specific `ioctl()` on a TCP socket and instruct Kernel to send those probes. There are 3 tunables to be enabled in registry:

- delay before 1st probe is sent (KeepAliveTime)
- delay between probes (KeepAliveInterval)
- number of lost probes, after this limit is reached, TCP connection is just cut off and your app will not be able to write into se socket anymore.